# wifi ping get high if I use extended monitor

Tags: wireless-networking, mac

I am using MBP 2017 13inch Mojave 10.14 with extended monitor connected through USB-C - displayport cable. I don't use any dongle, so signal interference is out of rule.

Before yesterday, everything is working fine, but yesterday I am playing with https://github.com/PBMacDev/ControlPlane/tree/mojave, I cannot download the released build, so I tried to build it on my own using Xcode. the build is successful but the app seems broken(?) so much GUI assets not showing.

I am giving it a try though, so I try to make a `ControlPlane` launch an app if I connected to my home wifi, after that I suddenly cannot browse anything though still connected to my wifi. but if I change to my personal hotspot everything was working fine.

now I reinstall my mac and delete the whole drive before, but the problem persist. pls help :(

Comment: I don't understand the connection between you building the application and your WiFI problems?  Care you clarify that point?

Comment: @Ramhound since the build has so many errors, it might contribute to my wifi problem, especially noting the coincidence.